# How to translate a CURL POST request into NodeRED

Tags: curl, post, node-red

I'm having problems translating the following CURL request into my NodeRED flow:

```
curl -X POST -u "apikey:my_api_key" -F "features=objects" -F "collection_ids=my_collection_ids" -F "image_url=my_image_URL" "API_url"
```

I created a function node and a HTTP request node (with the method set to POST and the URL set to "API_url").

In the function node I wrote the following code:

```
msg.headers = {}
msg.headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'apikey': 'my_api_key'
};

msg.payload = { }
msg.payload = { 
    'features': 'objects',
    'collection_ids': my_collection_ids',
    'image_url': my_image_URL'
};

return msg;
```

When I trigger the request, I get this error:

```
"{"code":401, "error": "Unauthorized"}"
```

am I doing a mistake passing the apikey in the header? any suggestions?
thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You could try to run the command directly in the machine (Raspberry Pi?) running node-red with the exec node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your authentication header.

When you pass `-u username:pass` to curl, it generates the appropriate `Authorization` header in the request which looks like:

```
Authorization: Basic dXNlcm5hbWU6cGFzcw==
```

This has the `username:pass` part encoded using base64.

So for your case, you should do the following to set the header properly:

```
msg.headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Authorization': 'Basic '+(new Buffer('apikey:my_api_key')).toString('base64')
};
```

Comment: It works! Thanks so much.

I also had to change the content-type as follows:
'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',